# Using setInterval with variable not working on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios7

I'm using `setInterval` with a `mousedown` event to continuously animate some divs like a slider.

I'm also setting a variable to `setInterval` so that I can stop the animation on `mouseup`.

This works fine except on iOS where it will only animate the divs if I remove the variable (int00) and operator in front of `setInterval` in the `mousedown` function:

```
var int00;

$('#scroll_diseases_left').mousedown(function(){
    int00 = setInterval(function() { scroll_diseases_left(); }, 250);
});

$('#scroll_diseases_left').mouseup(function(){
    clearInterval(int00);
});

function scroll_diseases_left() {
    $('#scroll_diseases_right').fadeIn();
    $('#disease_wrapper').animate({marginLeft: '-=50px'}, {duration: 500, queue: false, easing: 'linear'});
    $('#arthritis_content').animate({marginLeft: '-=50px'}, {duration: 500, queue: false, easing: 'linear'});
    $('#bleeding_content').animate({marginLeft: '-=50px'}, {duration: 500, queue: false, easing: 'linear'});
    $('#blood_vessel_content').animate({marginLeft: '-=50px'}, {duration: 500, queue: false, easing: 'linear'});
    $('#brain_content').animate({marginLeft: '-=50px'}, {duration: 500, queue: false, easing: 'linear'});
    $('#cancer_content').animate({marginLeft: '-=50px'}, {duration: 500, queue: false, easing: 'linear'});
}
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Declaring int00 as a local variable in the mousedown function works on iOS, but then I can't stop the animations...

```
$('#scroll_diseases_left').mousedown(function(){
    var int00 = setInterval(function() { scroll_diseases_left(); }, 250);
});

$('#scroll_diseases_left').mouseup(function(){
    clearInterval(int00);
});
```

Comment: FYI `setInterval` has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: Yes, I understand, and setInterval is working fine on iOS, the problem may be how I have used it with JQuery.

Comment: Is `int00` declared outside of your `mousedown` function?

Comment: No..but it works fine except on iOS...added that just now and still no go on iOS

Comment: The problem is not the int00, the problem is what you are doing. If you removed the int00 it changes the effect of the time, I think your problem is you need logic to test if int00 is set before you set it again, if it is, then the outcome if you reset it is different. I'm not sure what the desired effect is, but the logic is wrong. on IOS i assume you using a touch, so the event being fired is firing constantly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that the touch event on iOS wasn't being picked up.  This works:

```
  $('#scroll_diseases_left').bind('touchstart mousedown', function(){
   int00 = int00 || setInterval(function() { scroll_diseases_left(); }, 250);
  });

  $('#scroll_diseases_left').bind('touchend mouseup', function(){
      clearInterval(int00);
      int00 = undefined;
  });
```

Comment: Just as a note `As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers` from http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you need some logic to test if int00 is set before you reset it.

```
  var int00;

  $('#scroll_diseases_left').mousedown(function(){

   // if int00 is set, keep it, if it is not start a new interval.

   int00 = int00 || setInterval(function() { scroll_diseases_left(); }, 250);
  });

  $('#scroll_diseases_left').mouseup(function(){
      clearInterval(int00);
      int00 = undefined;
  });
```

Comment: note you must also set in00 to undefined so that it can be reset.

Comment: Still no go on iOS (7.1 on iPad), but works on Safari, Firefox, Google on Windows and Mac.

Comment: Note that if int00 = int00 || is removed the scroll_diseases_left function works, but of course the animations don't stop when the scroll_disease left button (the id) is no longer being touched.

Comment: Thanks @MartinWebb...this certainly helped, but the problem on iOS was the touch event was being picked up...see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here, but perhaps iOS doesn't like automatic globals.

Try placing `var int00;` before other code to declare the variable. It's good practice anyways.

Comment: I have other global variables working fine on iOS and just declared int00 like int00 = ''; above this script ...no difference